# Xvfb Jenkins plugin: Unrecognized option: -displayfd

Tags: selenium, plugins, jenkins, fatal-error, xvfb

**Jenkins version**: 1.573
Jenkins **Xvfb Plugin** version: 1.0.15 (latest)
**Linux OS**: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Tikanga)

**Xorg -version**

```
X Window System Version 7.1.1
Release Date: 12 May 2006
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0, Release 7.1.1
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.18-308.13.1.el5 x86_64 Red Hat, Inc.
Current Operating System: Linux kobaloki2 2.6.18-348.16.1.el5 #1 SMP Sat Jul 27 01:05:23 EDT 2013 x86_64
Build Date: 06 November 2012
Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.1.1-48.100.el5
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Module Loader present
```

**which Xvfb**

```
/usr/bin/Xvfb
```

I have some Selenium GUI based tests, that I'm running against a given environment/server's web site and where these tests check if everything for that site is working fine or not i.e. performing logging in / out and some other few clicks here n there successfully.

As these are Selenium GUI tests and I want to run these tests on a machine (Linux) in a **HEADLESS** mode, I need X display server (Xvfb).

I exported DISPLAY variable and started /etc/init.d/xvfb successfully.

```
root      5996     1  0  2014 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x8
```

I'm using **Xvfb plugin**, which is installed successfully on my Jenkins instance and configurations in both Jenkins Global and Jenkins job level is setup correctly and it's working fine if I run the job on master/slave instances (**NOTE**: *Currently I have created **2** slaves on the same master server but I have other separate servers where I'm planning to install more slaves*).

When I run only **2** simultaneous runs of the job, I see the following **additional** processes i.e. per run and the job finishes successfully. **NOTE**: *My offset value in Xvfb plugin is 1. If I use 100, then the following will show :101 and :102 respectively.*

```
u10003  16264  6921  1 12:56 ?        00:00:01 Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x8 -fbdir /production/JSlaves/kobaloki2_2/xvfb-2015-02-03_12-56-41-60597.fbdir
u10003  16289  6691  0 12:56 ?        00:00:00 Xvfb :2 -screen 0 1024x768x8 -fbdir /production/JSlaves/kobaloki2_1/xvfb-2015-02-03_12-56-46-7546741396559175462.fbdir
```

I trying to run concurrent runs of a Jenkins job (which **successfully** runs  Selenium GUI Integration/Acceptance tests on a master / slave servers).

**Now, What I'm trying to achieve is** to run multiple concurrent builds/runs of this Jenkins job (so that I can have multiple tests running at the same time i.e. to perform some kind of Volume based testing). *At this moment, I don't want to run these tests on a Selenium Grid server (out of scope of this post).*

[image]

**My questions**:

**1.** If the check box for "Let Xvfb choose display name" is checked, then I'm getting the following error *(here the job ran on a master Jenkins instance instead of a slave, thus /production/jenkinsAKS/... base folder)*. **How can I make Xvfb to use** *-displayfd* **variable successfully?**

```
13:33:01 Xvfb starting$ Xvfb -displayfd 2 -screen 0 1024x768x8 -fbdir /production/jenkinsAKS/xvfb-2015-02-03_13-33-00-6577455998897275731.fbdir
13:33:01 Unrecognized option: -displayfd

...
....bunch of options for Xvfb command
...
..
13:33:01 Fatal server error:
13:33:01 Unrecognized option: -displayfd
13:33:01 
13:33:11 
13:33:11 ERROR: Xvfb failed to start, consult the lines above for errors
```

Per this link: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin 
Let Xvfb choose display name Uses the **-displayfd** option of Xvfb by which it chooses its own display name by scanning for an available one. **This option requires a recent version of xserver, check your installation for support**. *Useful if you do not want to manage display number ranges but have the first free display number be used*.

**2.** In the above snapshot (Xvfb plugin), I see **Xvfb additional options** box, is there any option that I can try which will tell Xvfb to use a display# which is not currently in use?

**3.** It seems like I need to update X server version (Xorg -version). **How can I do that, what commands should I run**?

**4.** If I **un-check** the above mentioned checkbox and if I run multiple builds (**more than 2**) of this Jenkins job, then I get the following error if the DISPLAY number is already in use. *Using that checkbox in Xvfb plugin, I was trying to tell Xvfb to use the display number from the free list if one if not available.*

This error comes either for display #1 or #2 depending upon how Xvfb plugin assigns the number in Jenkins environment (using node/slave# etc).

```
13:04:27 Fatal server error:
13:04:27 Server is already active for display 1
13:04:27    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X1-lock
13:04:27    and start again.
13:04:27 
13:04:27 unlink: No such file or directory
13:04:42 unlink  failed, errno 2
13:04:42 ERROR: Xvfb failed to start, consult the lines above for errors

**How can I get rid of the above error** (seems like when I can resolve bullet 2 above)?
```

**NOTE:** If I use a single slave (either on the same master instance or on any other server) and increase the # of executors from 1/2 to 20 or greater, then, Xvfb is successfully running N number of builds/runs/tests at the same time without any failures. I can also use naginator plugin if required for retrying a failed build if any due to DISPLAY not available. BUT, this is not what I'm looking at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer time.

1. It depends on your machine i.e. Xvfb installed on your machine may not have -displayfd option (but may be a different similar one) but Xvfb plugin in Jenkins is passing it for you when you check that checkbox. Try a different option if available (see Xvfb help or man page on your OS machine). Now, I'm NOT using / checking this checkbox.
2. Actually not required as Xvfb plugin will generate a new instance and assign a DISPLAY (:NN) where NN is a number automatically per individual run.
3. I can use yum command.
4. This error doesn't come each time. If this happens and error comes in all Jenkins job runs, then you can run the following command to fix it.

   /etc/init.d/xvfb stop; sleep 2; /etc/init.d/xvfb start

To get a copy of xvfb file, you can get it online (where some xvfb file which sits under /etc/init.d folder, have more options that just stop/start.

Now, the solution to my ACTUAL problem (for which I was trying everything) is mentioned in other post here: [Xvfb, Jenkins, Selenium tests - Capture Screenshots of all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317039/xvfb-jenkins-selenium-tests-capture-screenshots-of-all-pages)